# What's the best way to reinstall curl on MacOS?

Tags: security, homebrew

I'm on MacOS, my Little Snitch firewall detected modification of curl. This could be an update or something else, but I wanna be 100% sure and want to reinstall curl.

What's the best way to do so on MacOS?

I was thinking to remove curl completely and reinstall with homebrew. The problem is that homebrew downloads packages using curl. I'm imagining an attack when modified curl could serve malicious packages for brew to install.

Maybe I'm overthinking, just wanna be 100% safe.

Comment: So if Curl is not installed, then how will Homebrew be able to download packages?

Comment: @SolarMike yeah, that's the problem. That's why i posted this question.

Comment: What is the path to curl that was updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curl` is installed as part of macOS, and is found at `/usr/bin/curl`. Since Catalina, this location is on a read-only system volume, so cannot be modified.

If you have installed another curl using homebrew, and it's this version that you suspect is modified, then you might want to do a 'clean' reinstall of homebrew, as if you hadn't already got it.

*"Little Snitch: providing you with data to worry about since 2003."*

Comment: haha. Yeah, I guess i'm just being paranoid. Thanks for the answer!